# How to get permission for using software screenshots in book?

Tags: legal, copyright, book

I am writing a book which includes a review of old software and I would like to add a couple of screenshots for some of them. How do I go about this legally or, alternatively, does this qualify as "fair use", without need for any explicit permission?

Have any of you already encountered this situation before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*Beware: Here are no lawyers!*

[Fair use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) includes *commentary, criticism, teaching.* So I guess you would be safe.

Especially in "the absence of a free alternative" as [Wikipedia puts it for its own screenshots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Non-free_software_screenshot).

*Beware: I'm not a lawyer!*

Answer (score 0):

Simply write to the publisher or author, you will usually find the appropriate contact information in the about screen. They will more than likely grant you permission.

Comment: I don't think OP is asking about using the screenshots for fiction; OP talks about a "review of old software," which is technical or nonfiction. So I think your first paragraph distracts from the answer here, and I'm editing it out.

Comment: Yes but what if the software in question is so old that its original company no longer exists?